# Grid view - Column

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

I am creating an application in asp.net..I used a grid view to show the datas .. By using the autogenerate columns

I bind the datas to the gridview.. Now i want to make a edit button at the end ..By clicking that the user can edit their details ...

But i need to count the number of columns in a row to make a pop up window to edit the details.. How to find out the number of columns in a autogenerated  grid..Number of columns varies depend upon the user..So how to find the number of columns..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get the no of columns through like this

int NoOfColumns=GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Count;

Answer (score 1):

You can find,
How many columns are in gridview with

```
GridView1.Columns.Count
```

How many cells are in one row of gridview with

```
GridView1.Rows[..].Cells.Count
```

Best Regards
Myra